# Ending loop for an appended list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to create a program that asks for users names in an appended list and then ends when the user types "q:. I have created the code to ask for names but am having trouble with where to end it. My loop is not breaking when I think it should. It keeps running

I have tried making it a for loop and a while loop and have had more success with a while loop but I could be incorrect.

```
# names of people that I know
names = ["Billy", "Trevor", "Rachel", "Victoria", "Steve"]
while True:
    names.append(input("Please enter your first name, "
                       "type q to exit: ", ))
    print(names)
    if names == "q":
        break
```

I expect the results to be:

```
Please enter your first name, type q to exit: jon
['Billy', 'Trevor', 'Rachel', 'Victoria', 'Steve', 'jon']
Please enter your first name, type q to exit: quit
['Billy', 'Trevor', 'Rachel', 'Victoria', 'Steve', 'jon', 'quit']
```

- Instead of quit I want the program to exit.

Comment: The answers given are all correct, but in your example you are typing `quit` instead of `q`.

Comment: @thefence2113 Is there a reason my answer was unaccepted? It is correct and also give  a choice of 2 approaches while highlighting the issue. It was accepted originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take your input in another variable called `name` and break the loop when you see q. Right now you are directly appending the input to `names` list

```
names = ["Billy", "Trevor", "Rachel", "Victoria", "Steve"]
while True:
    name = input("Please enter your first name, "
                       "type q to exit: ", )
    if name == "q":
        break
    names.append(name)
    print(names)
```

Comment: Great, please upvote/accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. But once you get a name from `input()` you immediately insert it into your list before checking if you want to quit the program. So the solution is to check for the quit signal then append the name.

```
# names of people that I know
names = ["Billy", "Trevor", "Rachel", "Victoria", "Steve"]
while True:
    name = input("Please enter your first name, "
                       "type q to exit: ", )
    if name == "q":
        break
    else:
        names.append(name)
print(names)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are already appending to the list before you do your check to see if it is 'q' or not. Also, from your question you want to quit on 'q' only. Not 'quit' or 'q'. If you want to check for 'quit' too then you should add that to your `if` condition.

Also, do this check and only append if it is not your exit condition. So I suggest this:

```
# names of people that I know
names = ["Billy", "Trevor", "Rachel", "Victoria", "Steve"]
while True:
    name = input("Please enter your first name, type q to exit: ")
    if name == "q" or name == "quit":
        break
    names.append(name)
print(names)
```

If you want to stick to your approach then before breaking you want to remove the last element because that would be a 'q' or a 'quit'. So:

```
names = ["Billy", "Trevor", "Rachel", "Victoria", "Steve"]
while True:
    names.append(input("Please enter your first name, "
                   "type q to exit: ", ))
    print(names) #Printing here will still show you the name 'q' or 'quit'. Move this down too.
    if names[-1] == 'q' or names[-1] == 'quit':
        names.pop() #This will remove the 'q' or 'quit'
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the whole list, `names` to `"q"` when checking to exit. Instead, you want to check if the most recent input was `"q"`.

You can do this by checking the last element in the list, e.g. by changing your condition to

```
if names[-1] == "q"
```

The rest of the code can be left the same.

Comment: That will solve the break point issue but not the fact that 'q' is appended to the list. So this won't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the list with string 'q', which will be false always. You can modify

```
while True:
    inp = input("Please enter your first name, "
                   "type q to exit: ", )
    names.append(inp)
    print(names)
    if inp == "q":
        break
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect and does the same thing the OP's code does.

Comment: I am checking inp with q, not the array. It is similar to your solution

Comment: @ksholla20 It still adds `q` to the names list though.

Comment: Yes you are checking inp with q, not the array but you already appended the input 'q' to names. That is still the issue.